# When my .NET code returned a Task, it wasn't doing the expected outcome. Changing it to async/await, fixed it. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have some pretty stock standard code for a typical .NET Core 2+ `program.cs`. I'm mainly setting up Logging.

With the code below, it's not `async/await` and the following happens:

- Logging occurs during the startup process 100%.
- the `CloseAndFlush();` occurs nearly instantly, before the rest of the app does stuff.
- No logging occurs in any controllers.

This is in part due to how Serilog works but that's not really the important bit, AFAIK.

The code steps right over `return CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();` .. when I thought this is the part where it would be `awaited` by the caller? When I debug my app, it does await (hang) on that line ... until the app has *completed* starting up. Once it's ready to accept connections, it then returns back here ... and runs through .. which means it calls `Log.CloseAndFlush()` and then `return Task.CompletedTask`.

Buggy Code:

```
public static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()....CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        // awaits here until the app has 100% started, then continues.
        return CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Logger.Fatal(exception, "Host terminated unexpectantly. Sadness :~(");
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Now changing this to `async/await` fixes everything. The code *does* correctly await on `return CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();` .. and then the `CloseAndFlush()` is called when the app is closing/terminating.

```
    public static async Task Main<T>(string[] args) where T : class
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()....CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            // Correctly waits here until the app explodes or ctrl-c has been pressed.
            await CreateWebHostBuilder<T>(args).Build().RunAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of an exception.");
        }

        Log.Debug("Finished shutting down app.");

        // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
```

Would returning a Task probably be only suitable if the method is only doing *one* `async/await` in it AND that is the last thing in the method?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, passing through a task only makes sense if your other method code doesn't depend on the outcome of the task which often will be the end of the method. However, you need to keep in mind that exceptions will only be raised when the task is awaited. Thus, if a task is passed through methods A and B, and only method C awaits, the exception stack trace will not contain A and B which might complicate debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a `Task`<sup>1</sup> instead of `await`ing it is your way of saying "there's nothing left for *this* method to do here"<sup>2</sup>.

If that's not the case (as here, where you don't want your finally clause to run yet), you're not done. You need some way of running some code at a later point in time, but you've got nothing useful to do *now*. And that's precisely what `await` allows you to signal.

---

<sup>1</sup>As [Jonas mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442927/15498), this is exactly true for non-`Task` returns too.

<sup>2</sup>I'm ignoring the case when you take a `Task` from elsewhere, add a `ContinueWith` and return the resulting `Task`, because there you're using a different mechanism to ensure you get to run code later and it's not *precisely* "this method" that runs in the continuation.

Answer (score 2):

> Would returning a Task probably be only suitable if the method is only doing one async/await in it AND that is the last thing in the method?

Basically, yes. Returning the task as in your first snippet will let the finally block run as you leave the scope, just like any other return statement inside a try with an associated finally. And as commented by ckuri your catch block won't do what you want either, as it will not catch exceptions from the task, only from the setup in `CreateWebHostBuilder` itself.